# Porcentaje valores columna

Tags: python, pandas

Busco el porcetaje de jugadores que se encuentran en peso tipo Delgadez - Porcetaje de jugadores que se encuentran en peso tipo Normal - Porcetaje de jugadores que se encuentran en peso tipo Sobrepeso - Porcetaje de jugadores que se encuentran en peso tipo Obeso. Todos ellos están recogidos en la columna IMC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como emplear bien python. Me sale el porcentaje de cada fila, pero no me agrupa por grupo (delgadez, normal, sobrepeso, obeso).

```
(df.groupby('IMC').size()/df['IMC'].count())*100
```

Comment: Será más fácil ayudarte si adjuntas un conjunto de datos de ejemplo sobre el cual poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Añadida una imagen del dataframe, gracias

Comment: Hola @ZenitPB ! Creo que sería más fácil, si en vez de agregar una imagen (que no se debe de hacer), creas un Dataframe con un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), que podamos copiar la creación de dicho DataFrame y reproducir tu problema, por ejemplo como ha hecho este otro usuario https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419677/matplotlib-subplots-cambia-las-fechas-del-eje-x

Answer (score 0):

Primero contaremos cuántos elementos de cada valor hay en tu df.
Eso lo haremos con el método [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).
Nos devolverá una tabla con cada valor que toma la columna `clasificacion_oms` y cuántas apariciones tiene cada valor.
Pero si además utilizamos su parámetro `normalize`, obtendremos las proporciones que buscas.

```py
porcentajes = df['clasificacion_oms'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Para acceder a cada valor lo hacemos simplemente:

```py
porcentajes['normal']
```