# Matplotlib Subplots cambia las fechas del eje X

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente Dataframe:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=5)
op = pd.DataFrame({'Op':["C","C","C","C","C"],
                   'Q': [1,1,1,2,3],
                   'P': [1, 1.5,2, 1.5, 1.5]},
                    index= dates)
op.plot()
```

[image: El eje de fechas funciona correctamente]

Pero si grafico utilizando subplots el eje *x* muestra incorrectamente los valores de las fechas del Dataframe.

```
fig ,ax= plt.subplots(2,sharex=True, figsize=(16,9))
ax[0].plot(op.P)
ax[1].plot(op.Q)
plt.show()
```

[image: como se aprecia los xtick son incorrectos]

Asimismo, este problema se arregla cuando agrego valores adicionales (rows) al dataframe. Por ejemplo, si tuviera 10 valores en lugar de 5.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Mis felicitaciones, un ejemplo de como debe de hacerse una buena pregunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te funciona ninguna solución, en ese caso siempre puedes modificar el indice a tu gusto, para que aparezca lo que tu desees. Por ejemplo así:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=5)
op = pd.DataFrame({'Op':["C","C","C","C","C"],
                   'Q': [1,1,1,2,3],
                   'P': [1, 1.5,2, 1.5, 1.5]},
                    index= dates)

#Aquí como cambio el indice
op.index = [idx[-2:] for idx in op.index.astype(str)]
op.index = ["01\njan\n2020"] + op.index[1:].tolist()

fig ,ax= plt.subplots(2,sharex=True, figsize=(16,9))
ax[0].plot(op.P)
ax[1].plot(op.Q)
plt.show()
```

### Explicación

1. Paso el indice a string con `op.index.astype(str)`.
2. Itero sobre dicho indice para quedarme solo con los días y lo asigno como el indice del dataframe `op.index = [idx[-2:] for idx in op.index.astype(str)]`
3. Para que quede igual que el indice de arriba, modifico el primer indice del DataFrame concatenando las listas `op.index = ["01\njan\n2020"] + op.index[1:].tolist()` (*esto no es necesario si te conformas con que aparezca 01*)

Como ves al pasar al indice a `str` puedo modificarlo a mi gusto, como cualquier `str` podrías incluir el més, el año, etc.

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la dedicada respuesta Alberto! Aunque todavía seguiré investigando porque al usar subplots() se produce esa distorción en las fechas! Saludos